# Layouts remains unchanged while trying to move from one activity screen to other

Tags: android, layout, android-intent

I'm trying to move from one activity screen to other by using the below code. 
The first activity MainActivity only has one button on clicking it I intend to invoke the other activity Menactivity but when I click the button nothing happens and after sometimes I get a prompt " unfortunately, application has stopped working. I've added the second activity in my manifest too. I'm getting Nullpointer exception as error and the thread fails to start.Please help.

```
      package com.example.samplexml;




        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;

     //First Activity (Mainactivity)

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               Button b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

               b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {

                          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                      }}); 

           }
        }


//Second Activity(Menactivity)

package com.example.samplexml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;


import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenActivity extends Activity {

    TextView  myTextView;
     EditText E1;
     EditText E2;
     EditText E3;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  Button b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
  Button b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
   E1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   E2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   E3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

  b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 




            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
            try {
                docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


            // root elements
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Class");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // staff elements
            Element student = doc.createElement("Student");
            rootElement.appendChild(student);


            // firstname elements
            Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
            firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(E1.getText().toString()));
            student.appendChild(firstname);

            Element Email = doc.createElement("Email");
            Email.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(E2.getText().toString()));
            student.appendChild(Email);

            // nickname elements
            Element Roll = doc.createElement("Roll_No");
            Roll.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(E3.getText().toString()));
            student.appendChild(Roll);


                    // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();



                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();


            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            File FF=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//new1.xml");
            //File FF=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//new.xml");
            try {
                if (FF.exists());
                    FF.delete();
                FF.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle the error here! don't ignore it. Either throw the exception all the way, or log it, or something.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(FF);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

                }
             catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             catch (TransformerException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();}  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                }
    });
  b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(MenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
      }}); 

  b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // Close the application
          finish(); }});
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please paste the whole error message?

Comment: you define 2 onClickListener() for single button..... b2 & b3 both connect with button3 id. check button declaration.

Comment: and also try to change getApplicationContext() instead of MainActivity.this.

Comment: post your activity_main.xml file..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sole piece of debugging information you've provided--you're getting a NullPointerException--it would seem that your intent is being fired correctly and that the problem lies in the construction of `MenActivity`.

In all likelihood, your inflated layout for that activity does not contain the IDs for `button1`, `button2` and/or `button3`.

Some **very basic** debugging would point out the exact line where your problem is.

Comment: 05-11 23:28:49.060: E/AndroidRuntime(28435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 23:28:49.060: E/AndroidRuntime(28435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.samplexml/com.example.samplexml.MenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 23:28:49.060: E/AndroidRuntime(28435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)

Comment: Your problem is clearly further down the stack trace, as you've only provided lines from the SDK packages.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I traced the problem in the code,you were right the problem was with the inflated layout.